# How to make an Webview based IOS app and being able to publish it

Tags: ios, webview, app-store, appstore-approval

I have a website which is responsive.
I built an app on android that is basically a webview that loads the website.

I would like to do the same on IOS but I know for a fact that there are a lot of restrictions about publishing web-view based application on app store.

- What can I add to my webview in order to gain the approval for sure ?
- I'm looking to be extremly lazy on this, is there an alternative
  that you may think of ?

*To the answer or comments about why bothering creating app if the website is enough. The answer is : for commercial reason and user friendliness reasons*

Answer (score 0):

Add some native controls or small extra features that your site doesn't have. You could add in native social sharing options, native navigation controls, etc. Uber is a hybrid app and so is some of Instagram I believe.

However the review process usually comes down to the reviewer, some are lax and some are not.